# how to make the box in my boxplot bigger?(matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

[image]

I use the matplotlib boxplot and plotted this graph. My question is how can I make the box larger or make the y-axis interval wider?

Comment: if you post your code, you'd have a chance at a more precise and informative answer

Answer (score 0):

To resize the plot or to enlarge the resulting image, you could tweak the `figsize` parameter in [matplotlib.pyplot.figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html).

To reduce the size of the markers to improve the visibility of the dots/circles, you could do that using the [linewidth](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linewidth) parameter.

You could share a snippet of your code for more accurate answers.